# Partial rendering performance with parameter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection and want to iterate and render a partial:

```
<% @programs.each do |program| %>
  <%= render "program", link: program_path(program) %>
<% end %>
```

For each rendering, I will pass a parameter called `link`. And it varies based on different situation.

- `program_path(program)`
- `admin_program_path(program)`
- `program.external_link`

However, it will spend a huge time to render every partial, so it's a N+1 problem. I also tried to render `collections` but I don't know how to pass the parameter.

Does anyone know a better way to do it? Or shall I give up partial and put those code to every page which rendering the partial?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**You could use:**

```
<%= render @programs %>
```

And create:

```
views/programs/_programs.html.erb
```

Then you choose the link with a condition in the partial.